# How can I set up AWS Aurora Serverless v2 Postgresql to do full text searches using tsvector in Hebrew?

Tags: amazon-web-services, full-text-search, hebrew, aws-aurora-serverless, postgresql-14

It seems that Hebrew is not one of the built-in supported languages and it doesn't seem like there is a way to add custom dictionaries in Aurora Serverless Postgresql.

Is there a way to get full text searching to work with Hebrew, and if so, how?

I thought that there might be a way to set up a custom dictionary using the .affix and .dict files that are available as part of Open Office (and other products/services).

However, even once I found the files, I didn't see a way to make them available to this version of Postgres.
On the other hand, it's hard to imagine that Amazon wouldn't provide a way to do full text searches in any language.